Is Bilibili or MxPlayer using their own video player for web streaming or using a third-party video player like 'ExoPlayer'?
I used many video player for online streaming. But In my opinion, YouTube's video player stands out as one of the best for online streaming which is build with ExoPlayer for Android. After using Billibilli.tv and MxPlayer, I find that they come close to ExoPlayer. I am curious to know about their streaming platform.
Are they using ExoPlayer for web streaming?
Thanks.
